# How to get the next element in a map function?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays

I have map function. It maps through one of twenty arrays, each contain 500 elements. The array is chosen through a state variable.

What I'm trying to do, is through each iteration of the function, add a table row element to my page. Theres a `th` tag and a `td` tag. They both recieve properties of an object to display

This idea works fine when it's just accessing the element being iterated over, but I'm trying to access the next element so I can display that it the next two elements on the same row.

I read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) that you can access another element by referring to the original array like so:

```
var newArray  = myArray.map(function(value, index, elements) {
  var next = elements[index+1];
  // do something
});
```

or...

```
var newArray  = myArray.map(function(value, index) {
  var next = myArray[index+1];
  // do something
});
```

Problem is that when I try this, my app crashes and so does my whole computer. I can't figure out why.

Here's the code I have for the map function:

`AR_concSplits` is an array of arrays that are broken down from an original one that's 10k elements long

`ST_ArrayMarker-1` is a state variable that changes the array used by the below function, re-rendering it

`bark()` is just my shorthand version of console.log

I'm also using styled-components, which is why there are weird tag names.

I don't get any crashes when I comment out the `{elements[index+1]}` and `{elements[index+2]}` lines, so these are the problem...somehow.

```
    {AR_concSplits[(ST_ArrayMarker-1)].map((thing, index, elements) => (
    (index === 0 || index % 2 === 0) ?
    <> 
         

            <TableRow NoHoverTR inputHeight="20px" inputBackgroundColour="gray" inputFontColour="black">
            
            {/* left hand record */}
            <SuperTH inputWidth="10px" inputPadding="0px">
                {thing.id}
            </SuperTH>
            <SuperTD NoHoverTD inputBackground="black">
                {thing.text}
            </SuperTD>

            {/* right hand record */}
            <SuperTH inputWidth="10px" inputPadding="0px">
            {elements[index+1]}
                
            </SuperTH>

            <SuperTD NoHoverTD inputBackground="black">
            {elements[index+2]}
            </SuperTD>

            </TableRow>
    </>
    :
    <>
        {bark('Index was odd. Skipping to next')}

    </>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I the case when you have your `index = AR_concSplits[(ST_ArrayMarker-1)].length - 1;` and `index = AR_concSplits[(ST_ArrayMarker-1)].length;`
This lines will throw Array Out of Bounds exception

```
<SuperTH inputWidth="10px" inputPadding="0px">
        {elements[index+1]}
        </SuperTH>

        <SuperTD NoHoverTD inputBackground="black">
        {elements[index+2]}
        </SuperTD>
```

, since elements[index+1] and elements[index+2] will be referencing non existing index in the array.

Comment: Ah the array would be out of bounds? But I thought `elements` would allow me to use the entire array?